# Optimize HTMLAgilityPack.LoadHtml

Tags: c#, visual-studio

We have a project where we are analyzing over 90,000 HTML files stored locally. We are running tests against these files as a part of data analysis.

We obviously are working to optimize our code so that our tests can run as fast as possible eliminate wasted time. When we initially started our tests took about 4 hours to run, through using the Visual Studio Performance Profiler we were able to find bottlenecks and reduce the running time to about 30 minutes.

According to the Visual Studio Performance Analyzer a large chunk of the running time is eaten up by this following lines of code:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgillityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html); // specifically this line here
```

These HTML files are stored on our local disk and will never change - I thought about possibly caching a serialized copy of the "doc" object and retrieving deserializing to avoid having to call the LoadHtml method - however, the HtmlAgiltiyPack.HtmlDocument class it not marked as Serializble and i'm not even certain if the deserialization would be faster than the LoadHTML method.

We only need to execute xpath statements against the htmldoc - so i'm not sure if there is another way to execute xpath that doesn't require the conversion to HtmlDocument - i'm guessing not.

Does anyone else have any ideas on how we might be able to optimize this / cache it somehow so that we dont need to constantly call the LoadHTML method?

thanks!

Comment: HTML Agility Pack is [on GitHub](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack) and has an [MIT Licence](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/LICENSE). You could make your own fork and add whatever functionality you need. (And even turn it into a pull request if you think this is something other people might benefit from)

Comment: You mention html pages are not going to change. Try restricting the parts of the pages you expect the data to come from and save smaller versions of the original documents. Another time consuming task that HAP does is amending a lot of syntax errors and issues in the html. If you trust html is correct this could be disabled, otherwise load them as HAP document, save them as file and disable validations on parsing.

Comment: Did you try to read them with some xml reader instead? Maybe that would be faster, and xpath queries are still possible.

Comment: @derloopkat - going to try that... great idea.

Comment: @Evk - going to try that - thank you

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - thanks - we are actually reviewing the htmlagiltypack code now to see if we can optimize for our use case

Comment: @Evk, html very often breaks any Xml reader, you find things like `<br>` in lots of pages, an even other unclosed tags. That's the point on using HAP for .Net. Html is not standard Xml.

Comment: @derloopkat yes but here pages are static, so OP can convert them to valid xhtml first, if they are not already.

Comment: @Evk, yes.Also get rid of any Javascript code. Think that something like a>5 also can break Xml.